# Hide AJAX controller calls in console

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebug

I am developing a application based on Spring MVC(using tiles as view resolver).

the application has some dropdown lists that are populated with values fetched from the DB.

The dropdown list

```
<form:select id="idServiceUnit" path="serviceUnit" multiple="multiple"></form:select>
```

AJAX call to the controller(included in a seperate js file)

```
jq.ajax({
        url: "/MRYWeb/getServiceUnitLookUp",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(data){              
          jq("#idServiceUnit").addOption(data,{},false,{},{});
          jq("#idServiceUnit").multiselect({
                noneSelectedText:"Select",
                selectedList: 3, 
                height:150,
                minWidth:195,
                beforeclose:function(){
                    fnCustomizedTextForMultiSelect('idServiceUnit');
                }
                }).multiselectfilter();
    }
    });
```

/MRYWeb/getServiceUnitLookUp is the relative URL of the controller that returns a list to populate the dropdown

it is working fine but when ever i'm loading the page, firebug actually intercepting the URL

http://i.minus.com/ieYZJj8eC6jlr.JPG

as well as intercepting the js file call

http://i.minus.com/ibkGiljg3dpXUl.JPG

our client thinks it is a security risk. So can anyone help me by giving me idea about hiding these URL's or hiding the js call itself??

Comment: I dont think its a security risk. If you wont allow, ajax calls cannot be done cross domain. Its the way things work. Once its on client side, you can do nothing to hide anything.

Answer (score 1):

> our client thinks it is a security risk.

The URLs allow access to data which you are going to display to the user. It is not a security risk for them to see the data before you format it.

Just make sure that you don't send data you need to keep secret, and that you perform authentication & authorisation when the data should only be sent to some users.

> So can anyone help me by giving me idea about hiding these URL's or hiding the js call itself??

You can't.

The browser belongs to the user, not the web author. If you ask their browser to do something, then they are able to see it (and stop it or change it).

Answer (score 0):

This is the web my friend. It is a security risk but the only way that you can get away of this is get off of internet. Show to him his bank site, the ajax calls are there too...